How to use GPU after numba.cuda.close()?
I am using tensorflow on jupyter notebook. Suppose I want to flush everything in my GPU memory without restarting the kernel (that means without touching my RAM contents). Please do not dive into the reasons behind my demand; at the end I should be able to clear the GPU memory at will.
There are tons of discussions on this simple question but without a clear answer. However, I have seen many recommending numba.cuda.close(). But this causes issues for me, eventually killing the kernel and defeating my purpose.
Below is a basic code.
#---- cell 1 ----
import tensorflow as tf
from numba import cuda 

#---- cell2 ----
a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

#---- cell3 ----
#device = cuda.get_current_device(); device.reset()
cuda.select_device(0); cuda.close()

After cell3, the memory is released but when I attempt to execute cell2 again, the kernel dies. In fact, in a fresh kernel once I execute cell2 and cell3 then I can never execute cell2 again without killing the kernel no matter what I do. I am puzzled. Same thing happens if I use device = cuda.get_current_device(); device.reset() inseatd of cuda.close().
So my questions are.

Can I again use the GPU after executing cuda.select_device(0); cuda.close()? If so, how? Note that this question was asked before here but there is no clear answer.
If this problem with cuda.close() cannot be avoided is there a better solution for releasing all GPU memory without touching anything on RAM in ipython notebook?  tf.keras.backend.clear_session() did not release the memory in the first place.


No, you can’t use numba.cuda.close in the way you are trying and it makes to no sense to do so. Further, using numba to try and manipulate the context being used by another framework like Tensorflow is dangerous and likely to fail

Thank you for a clear answer. There must be a way to clear GPU memory, that is the answer to my 2nd question.

There is not, in the general case, if you refuse to consider options like shutting down the notebook kernel.  Good luck!


Can I again use the GPU after executing cuda.select_device(0); cuda.close()?

Not in the sense you are imagining. Those two API calls will first bind to and then destroy the current GPU context. While that will release the resources held in the context (i.e. all the memory), it will also destroy all the state which was initialised by Tensorflow and the CUDA libraries which it relies upon, likely rendering them non-functional. You shouldn’t expect anything to work after that.

… is there a better solution for releasing all GPU memory without touching anything on RAM in ipython notebook?

That question shows a fundamental misunderstanding of the problem. The entire source of your issue is that there are Python objects in the Python interpreter memory (what you refer to as “RAM in the ipython notebook”) which hold large amounts of resources on the GPU. Until they are destroyed, their GPU resource footprint remains (and that presumes they are properly designed and release all the GPU resource they hold when they are deleted). By definition, you can’t achieve what you want without not “touching anything on RAM”.
I recommend you familiarise yourself thoroughly with the Python garbage collector and best practices for ensuring that reference counting doesn’t get defeated by the code you write. That is the secret to ensuring good resource management in Python code, especially when using frameworks which allocate resources outside of the standard Python memory manager.
And if you can’t or won’t do that, restarting the Python interpreter is going to be the only way to free up resources on the GPU.

Thank you for a clear answer. However, my original problem was I could not train my models iteratively (with different batch size) as I am working with a very large dataset that barely fits into my GPU; even with gc.collect(). If there is no way of clearing the GPU memory 'without touching my RAM', I will ask this question separately, explaing with a MWC.

But it still puzzles me as I think more about it.
Step 1: Suppose I read a huge data set in a numpy array, A. This is in my RAM, nothing in my GPU yet, right? I can confirm this as nvitop shows no GPU usage till now.
Step 2: I do the training, my GPU memory is now being consumed. Why can't I  flush whatever there is in my GPU while the array A remains in my RAM?
